# Get the task_name from AsyncResult when submitting chains in celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd

How am I supposed to retrieve a **task's name** when I've got its `AsyncResult` object and consequently its `id`?

For example if I launch two of my tasks in a chain:

```
>>> task_chain = (task_A.s() | task_B.s())
>>> async_result = task_chain.apply_async()
```

I can retrieve the `id` of **task_B** and consequently **task_A** using the internal `_parents()` method like this:

```
>>> async_result.id
>>> 2ed28e84-0673-4491-a56f-c5ab8dfb5725
>>> async_result._parents()[0].id
>>> e793f4dc-5110-4f57-8f98-8caa48c40528
```

However when I attempt to retrieve the task_name I get nothing back:

```
>>> async_result.task_name
>>> async_result._parents()[0].task_name
```

Why is this happening? Could this possibly be a bug?
I have noticed that by submitting a single task, the `task_name` attribute of `AsyncResult` works perfectly fine and returns the proper task name.

Is there any other way to retrieve a task's name from the AsyncResult object?

Thank you all in advance.

P.S.
I have already found a similar question here but no one seems to propose a pratical and working solution.

[celery-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/celery-users/task_name/celery-users/HUTnmRYscPI/fHnIJXtNAtYJ)

**UPDATE**

Apparently it seems that I've a hit a wall with this one. There is an open ticket on github about the exact same issue with the difference that it concerns groups instead of chains.

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2504

Answer (score -3):

One way to do it save it into the cache like that:

```
cache.set(hash_key, result, 30)  # save result to cache for 30 seconds
```

and you can retrieve it by its key:

```
result = cache.get(hash_key)
```

Assuming its not InMemory cache

**UPDATE**

Sorry I've misinterpreted the question.

What I think happened is that the result of the task_chain AsyncResult gets initialized with only the task id as its the only requirement. Maybe if you try that:

```
async_result = task_chain.apply_async(name="mytasks")
```

but I would't count on it

Comment: Your first answer is irrelevant. Your update on the other hand suggests using the `name` parameter of the `apply_async` method which takes no such attribute.